# How to use Beautifulsoup to get text from <span tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need a little help with my code. I am learning Python and beautiful soup in order to **scrape** some data from the Dell website.

I need to get the service tag, warranty and service code from a particular server but I am not understanding how to navigate the HTML tree.

This is my code so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'/Users/peterfranca/Downloads/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cadhs1/product-support/servicetag/0-NE9lVXI4NlpmbjFtRHJBbTF0dDhoQT090/overview")

time.sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for model in soup.findAll('h1', {'class':'mb-3 mb-lg-1 text-center text-lg-left position-relative word-break'}):
    print(model.text)

for tag in soup.findAll('p', {'class':'service-tag mb-0'}):
    print(tag.text)

for warranty in soup.findAll('p', {'id':'warrantyExpiringLabel'}):
    print(warranty.text)

for sertag in soup.findAll('p', {'class':'font-weight-medium text-jet'}):
    print(sertag.text)

driver.quit()
```

The last "for" is where I can't figure out how to get the correct data.

```
for sertag in soup.findAll('p', {'class':'font-weight-medium text-jet'}):
    print(sertag.text)
```

Basically, I would like to run the above block of code and get the below output.

```
Express Service Code: 14270045690
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Can anyone also explain to me how to navigate in the right way in the HTML tree?

Comment: check below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for sertag in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'font-weight-medium text-jet'})[1]:
    print(sertag, sertag.next_element.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks again @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη. You are such a nice guy. Learning this lib is being a learning curve for me, but I will not give up.

Comment: Could you also explain the code?
I understand that the [1] means the second element for that class, is this correct?
What sertag.next_element.strip()) is exactly doing? Sorry for all the noob questions.

Comment: @PeterFranca you welcome, yes we are using the index of `[1]`. then we are picking up the [next_element](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element) and then we using [strip()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip) to get rid of `spaces`